# UIPageControl + UIAppearance

Tags: ios, ios6, uipagecontrol, uiappearance

The docs for UIAppearance is extremely poor.

I want to customize the colours for a UIPageController, but I am unable to figure out which properties to set. When I go `[UIPagecontrol appearance] set` I get probably hundreds of options, so it's nearly impossible to figure out what's what.

I would assume it's possible with UIAppearance proxy, right?

Thank you

Comment: The release notes seem to have enough info to get started: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1 A key point seems to be to check the headers for UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR ("Marks a method that participates in the appearance proxy API.")

Comment: I don't think UIPageControl adopts the UIAppearance protocol. Page controls are relatively trivial to implement; you will probably have to make your own or find an open source one. Like https://github.com/honcheng/iOS-StyledPageControl.

Comment: Just an update for anyone reading this, UIPageControl will support the UIAppearance protocol in iOS 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIAppearance` protocol was added to `UIPageControl` as of iOS 6.

The properties you can customise are:

- Dot tint colour
- Highlighted dot tint colour

This is an excerpt from *UIPageControl.h*, as you can see these `UIAppearance` additions are only available from iOS 6.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *pageIndicatorTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *currentPageIndicatorTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```