# UIPageControl - How to make the background transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I am using `UIPageControl` and trying to make the background transparent.

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Any suggestions?

Tried

```
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

no luck.

============

Okay, as mentioned by **@powerj1984** and **@daniellarsson** `UIPageControl` seems to be not alterable with respect to position and background color.

So I decided to move this to UIViewController and created a `UIPageControl` and

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

And then bring this to top of my `UIPageViewController` as in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.pageTitles.count;    
[self.view addSubview:_pageControl.viewForBaselineLayout];
```

Then I updated the index of `UIPageControl` in `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController`

```
NSUInteger index = ((HomePageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex; 
self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
```

Comment: Unless this was updated in iOS 7 I don't think background color is an option for UIPageControl appearance, see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881088/uipagecontrol-uiappearance

Comment: What color is it now? I don't think you can edit the background color through appearance anymore, and I would assume that it was transparent by default?

Comment: Its white by default and I added this via presentationCountForPageViewController and presentationIndexForPageViewController. When I add via Storyboard as page control its transparent.

Comment: Can you see the dots?

Comment: @sselvan I'm having the exact same problem, could you be more verbose on how you overcome this problem, you could answer your own question for this matter

Comment: try to use this 'pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0) green:(0.0) blue:(0.0) alpha:(0.1)];'

Comment: I had an issue with this also, but then I realized that I had been following along with an app coda tutorial, and I had forgotten to take their custom styling of the UIPageControl in my AppDelegate.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, as mentioned by @powerj1984 and @daniellarsson UIPageControl seems to be not alterable with respect to position and background color.

So I decided to move this to UIViewController and created a UIPageControl and

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

And then bring this to top of my UIPageViewController as in viewDidLoad

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.pageTitles.count;    
[self.view addSubview:_pageControl.viewForBaselineLayout];
```

Then I updated the index of UIPageControl in viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController

```
NSUInteger index = ((HomePageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex; 
self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
```

Comment: i have exactly this same problem. i need to change the background colour of the page control as transparent and i need to show the pageIndicator dots.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Mostly worked for me... now the problem is that when I scroll backwards (I only have 2 pages), it doesn't update the currentPage. This is because it doesn't call `viewControllerBeforeViewController` until after it has made the transition, so the index is again 0 and the method will return nil.

Comment: this link is helpful http://samwize.com/2016/03/08/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-custom-uipagecontrol/

Answer (score 5):

```
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

is working but!! than you have to set the `backgroundColor` of the `UIPageViewController` also on `[UIColor clearColor]` and than! you will see the backgroundcolor of the container view.

```
- (void)initPageViewController
{
    _pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                      navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                    options:nil];

    UIImageView *imgView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NiceBGImage"];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    _pageController.view.frame = ({
        CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        frame;
    });

    _pageController.delegate = self;
    _pageController.dataSource = self;
    _pageController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSArray *controllers = @[_controllers[0]];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:controllers
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];

    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pageControl = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[_pageController class], nil];

    [self addChildViewController:_pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:_pageController.view];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Page control is transparent by default.**

Check with this sample code:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 8;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pageControl];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Please find the more customization possibilities below

**Appearance of Page Controls**

You can customize the appearance of a page control by setting the properties depicted below.

[image]

To customize the appearance of all page controls in your app, use the **appearance proxy** (for example, [UIPageControl appearance]). For more information about appearance proxies, [see Appearance Proxies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW18).

**Tint Color**

The only way to customize the appearance of a page control is by setting custom tints for the dots representing each page. The Current Page (currentPageIndicatorTintColor) field affects the color of the dot representing the currently displayed page, and the Tint Color (pageIndicatorTintColor) field affects the color of the dots representing every other page. The default color is white for the current page dot, and translucent gray for the other page dots.

[image]

If you want your custom colors to be translucent, you must specify a color with an alpha value of less than 1.0. This must be done programmatically, as in the following example:

```
self.myPageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
self.myPageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Check more details in [UIPageControl - Developer.Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPageControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIPageControl)

Comment: This is more for the dots, not seem to be for background - the black bg that you see there

Comment: @sselvan: I clearly mentioned that "Page control is transparent by default"

Comment: hmmm, I am still a noob here, it had white background by default.

Comment: Anyways I overcame with a different solution which I updated in my question

Comment: @sselvan: check my updated answer and try the code. Let me know the result. transparent or white background !!!. It should be transparent.

Comment: @Ramshad indeed the background colour isn't transparent by default, and I don't mean the page indicator, those are transparent but not the area below them.

Comment: @Kira: are you using ios7?

Comment: @Ramshad I'm using ios7, yes

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1.1, I know that setting the background color of a UIPageControl object to the clear color worked for me.

```
[[self pageControl] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a working solution for this problem in Swift. You can find the original code and answer in this [link](http://tunesoftware.com/?p=3363).

It requires you to override the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function to bring the page control to the front of the view.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let subViews: NSArray = view.subviews
        var scrollView: UIScrollView? = nil
        var pageControl: UIPageControl? = nil

        for view in subViews {
            if view.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
                scrollView = view as? UIScrollView
            }
            else if view.isKindOfClass(UIPageControl) {
                pageControl = view as? UIPageControl
            }
        }

        if (scrollView != nil && pageControl != nil) {
            scrollView?.frame = view.bounds
            view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could work if you set the background color of the `UIPageControl` to a **background image** that looks the same as your VC's *background color*:

```
[UIPageControl appearance].backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pageControllerBackground"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer with extension of Juan Ariza

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let subViews: NSArray = view.subviews
    var scrollView: UIScrollView? = nil
    var pageControl: UIPageControl? = nil

    for view in subViews {
        if view.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
            scrollView = view as? UIScrollView
        }
        else if view.isKindOfClass(UIPageControl) {
            pageControl = view as? UIPageControl
            pageControl?.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            pageControl?.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            pageControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
    }

    if (scrollView != nil && pageControl != nil) {
        scrollView?.frame = view.bounds
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];

//for change the bullets color
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(129.0/255) green:(129.0/255) blue:(129.0/255) alpha:1.0];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(06.0/255) green:(122.0/255) blue:(145.0/255) alpha:1.0];

pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: [[self pageControl] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; worked for me as of Xcode 6.1.1. Just FYI for anyone looking for a solution on how to set the UIPageControl's background to be transparent.