# Remove white background from page view controller indicator

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to remove the white background from the UIPageViewController indicator? Here is the code that I am using below. The code snippet below is from the AppDelegate script.

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
//pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

As you can see I have commented out the `pageControler.backgroundColor = ...` line to see if that would change but no. I am using Swift in Xcode. Here is a screenshot to show you what I mean:

[image]

UPDATE:
I have looked at this similar question ([UIPageControl - How to make the background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007434/uipagecontrol-how-to-make-the-background-transparent)) but this does not address the problem. I have used the following code in the AppDelegate but no luck. Here is the code used:

`pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

UPADATE 2:
Here is the code used in the `viewDidLoad()`.

```
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPageControl - How to make the background transparent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007434/uipagecontrol-how-to-make-the-background-transparent)

Comment: @sjwarner I use this piece of code but it still does not fix the problem. 'pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()'

Comment: I guess that the white sash at the bottom is not related to the control itself (its far to large and the control isn't even centered). Can you share some info about the views and the layout on this controller?

Comment: @Alladinian See Update 2 in the question.

Comment: @JohnGool So, as @Alladinian has implied, the white is simply your `self.view`. If you don't like it, change `self.view.backgroundColor`. Also you might need to change `self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor`.

Comment: Also, the code you tried and rejected makes no sense. You said: "Is it possible to remove the white background from the UIPageViewController indicator" But then you said `pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`. That would not _remove_ the white background, it would _add_ the white background!

Comment: @matt Yes that is true but as I mentioned in the question, I have commented the 'pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()' to show that I have removed the white background. I have set a blue background in the main.storyboard but the question is to remove the white blocks.

Comment: I see no "white blocks". If you are in doubt of what is white behind the page control, use View Debugging. It will show you.

Comment: @matt What I mean by "white blocks" are the two white sash located at the top and bottom of the view (see the screenshot in the question)

Comment: And I explained to you what they are and how to change their color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's concentrate on the white at the *top* of the view. You are saying:

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)
```

So with the number `30` you yourself are leaving a gap at the top: `self.pageViewController.view.frame` starts 30 pixels down from the top of `self.view`. Thus we see the color of `self.view` showing in the gap. If you don't like that color, change it by changing `self.view.backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

@matt helped me to get this answer, but for anyone reading this in the future who has the same problem to remove the white from the top and bottom of the screenshot in my question, all you need to do is, set the color of view to 'default' in the main.storyboard and in the ViewController that you using, change color using something like this:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 0.7, alpha: 100)
```

Hope this helps!